# Vim: \n vs. \r

Tags: windows, unix, vim

I haven't used vim in a Unix system in a while, but as I recall there was no \r, it was always \n.

I'm using gVim under windows and when I *search* for new line characters I use \n. Searching for \r returns nothing. But when I *replace* the characters I have to use \r's. \n's give me ^@

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: You should change the accepted answer; Jonathan Leffer's answer is correct but has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Lookup up:

```
:set fileformat=unix
:set fileformat=dos
```

This can be used on either platform to switch to the other encoding.

Comment: I don't see what the file's EOL format has to do with the way vim searches/replaces newlines/carriage returns.

Comment: Normally, you set the file format appropriately and then you don't have to worry about whether carriage returns are needed, and hence don't have to search for them.

Comment: I would say this solution is the simplest! I perfectly work for my case.

Answer (score 30):

Looks like you're asking two things.  One issue is `\r` vs. `\n` which others have covered.

The other issue is `\n` on the right side of a substitution.  If you look at `:h s/\n`, it says that `\n` in the replacement part of a substitution inserts a `<NUL>` / `<NL>`, NOT a newline.

If you do a `:%s/\n/\n/` and save and open the file in a hex editor, all the `^@` characters are ASCII 0's (NUL characters).  Why the Vim devs use `\n` on the left for end-of-line and `\n` on the right for NUL is beyond me.  But this particular behavior has nothing to do with Windows vs. Unix.

Comment: This one always gets me - I can never remember whether it's \r or \n that means different things in search and replace.  Recently (after I actually read the docs and found what the difference is) I find it useful to remember that NUL starts with 'n'.

Comment: No doubt there's logic in the choices the designers made but it trips me up too everytime. To me, it would have made much more sense to use `\r` *(or \n, pick you choice)* in both search and replace. Using `s/\r/\r/n`should return 1 instead of Pattern not found and using `s/\n/\n` shouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 8):

Behind the scenes, Vim uses \r (carriage returns) to save End-Of-Lines (regardless of the fileformat, which only matters when the file is being read or written).  Vim uses \n to represent NULs.  However, you search for EOL as \n, but in the replacement, \n stands for NUL.  It's explained in :h sub-replace-sepcial.  Searching for \r will find carriage returns that weren't part of the fileformat's EOL.  There is a long explanation at :h file-formats.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> :%s/^V^M/^V^M/g
> ```

Similarly, the following does the same thing (I think), and is easier to type out.

```
:%s/\r/\r/g
```

Answer (score 3):

vim does some messing around with carriage returns (\r) and newlines (\n).  For instance, if you're in Unix and vi shows you lines ending in '^M' because they're Windows text files, an easy way to get rid of them is to enter the command

```
:%s/^V^M/^V^M/g
```

It doesn't look like it should do anything, but it does.

Answer (score 2):

Under unix, inside vim, `^V` + `<enter>` gives me a `^M` which is the `\r` character.

Also, you can't find `\r` inside vim unless you tell it to edit the file in binary mode, that is, not using the default automatic mode where it autodetects the line ending. (it should print `[dos]` in the status.)

Comment: FWIW, if your file has a mix of some lines terminating in \n but other lines terminating in \r\n, you'll see the ^M characters.  You may get a mix if someone performed an edit on the text file using Windows.

Comment: Yes, of course, vim will choose the line ending that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might lie in the way that Windows and Unix do newlines. The format for Unix is \n (line feed) but for Windows it is \r\n (carriage return, line feed).

Comment: You have that backwards,  UNIX does \n (which is line feed), Windows does \r\n (carraige return, line feed),

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, if you open up a file in text mode, \n is interpreted as both the newline and linefeed characters.  This normally isn't the case the *nix systems.