# Unable to replace a space with a new line in Vim

Tags: vim

I know the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350661/vim-n-vs-r).

I run

```
:%s/ /s/\n/g
```

I get

```
E488: Trailing characters
```

**2nd example**

I run

```
:%s/ /\n/g
```

I get

```
text^@text
```

I run the same codes also with the following settings separetaly

```
set fileformat=unix
```

and

```
set fileformat=dos
```

**How can you replace with a new line in Vim?**

Answer (score 193, accepted):

`:%s/ /`<kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>`/g`

Where <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd> is Control-key plus key v  and <kbd>Return</kbd> is the return key (the one on the main keyboard, not the enter key on the numpad). The other characters are typed as usual.

If this is entered correctly, the sequence <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> will display as the characters `^M`, typically in a different color, to indicate that they are special. Note that actually typing `^M` will *not* work.

Also note that in Vim for windows, it's Control-q instead of Control-v (as that is paste).

---

Ctrl-v also allows entering other "special" keys via the keyboard. It is also useful for e.g. Tab or Backspace.

Comment: I accept the answer because it is most system independent. samoz answer also works. It is surprising that the command for Windows works in my OS/X, not the Unix command.

Comment: @rangalo: :%s/ /\r/g works fine for me too, but not the :%s/ /\n/g.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clear which keys to press.

Comment: To be honest, the key sequence made no sense at first. But after taking a moment to appreciate it, it now makes perfect sense; pasting in a return code. Thanks for sharing @sleske.

Comment: ... this doesn't work. Ctrl+V pastes whatever you have in the clipboard... So you **first** have to copy a newline into the clipboard, *then* you can run `:%s/ /<Ctrl+v>/g`, no Return necessary.

Comment: @GACy20: It does work for me (tested in vim on Linux, and gVim on Windows). As I wrote in my answer, some versions of vim may use Ctrl-Q instead of Ctrl-V. What vim version/executable did you use?

Comment: @sleske Windows Terminal + WSL, everything with default settings. Neither Ctrl+V nor Ctrl+Q does anything useful for this case. If I copy a newline (e.g. from notepad++), then yes using Ctrl+V will insert a return code (in which case no following "Return" is needed).

Comment: @GACy20: Hm- maybe a problem with Windows Terminal interfering? It seems that is configurable: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5641 . As a reference: I use cmd.exe + WSL + vim, it works for me.

Comment: On Mac, this worked for me using `:%s/  /s/<ctrl+q><Return>/g` - thanks!

Answer (score 71):

Try

```
%s/ /\r/g
```

Answer (score 8):

Enter the following:

```
:s/ /
```

and now type Ctrl-V or Ctrl-Q (depends on your configuration) and hit the Enter key. You should now have:

```
:s/ /^M
```

Finish it off:

```
:s/ /^M/g
```

and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically to answer your problem with trailing characters, this is the regex you specified:

```
:%s/ /s/\n/g
```

You have too many `/`.  What happens is that you replace ' ' with `s`, and then you tag on this after the substitution: `\n/g`

I think you meant this:

```
:%s/ \s/\n/g
```

Note that your `/s` was changed to `\s`.  Now the substitution will replace one space followed by one whitespace of any kind (space or tab) with `\n`.  I doubt if this solve the problem or replacing space with a newline, but it should explain the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try either

For Unix:

```
:1,$s/\ /\n/g
```

For Windows:

```
:1,$s/\ /\r/g
```

This contains an escape character for the space.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to give that a try.